# Validating input data with the criteria specified in a database field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

How do I validate the input data with the criteria specified in the database?

Suppose, I have a database to support upto 255 characters in the username. Now, while validating the input data, instead on hardcoding the maximum no of characters allowed (let say 80 ) in the username, how can I go about storing the maximum no of allowed characters in a settings table and then using that value to validate the input data.

Basically I want to give administrator a choice to configure the max allowed characters from within admin panel.

Is there any way to achieve it, without having to use the custom validation rules?

**Edit :** 
Let say, we have a database field of type char(255) to store email. An admin may not necessarily want to allow an email over 30 characters in length, in that case he can configure a setting to allow maximum no of characters in the email, the set value will be stored in the database and will be used for the future validation purpose.

Comment: Why not set the maximum field length from the config parameter? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

Comment: @Patrick That works well for the html element and should be done.  However, you still have to validate client side.  That value can be circumventing pretty easy.

Comment: That's not the problem.  I want to set the maximum theoretical size on the database while giving the admin choice to set the maximum allowed size according to his choice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give the administrator the possibility to define the validation rule itself.

I suppose you have a db table with the validation rules, something like this:

**validation_rules** table example structure:

```
id          | INT
field_name  | VARCHAR(50)
field_rules | VARCHAR(50)

...other fields you may need...
```

So, when you have to validate it, you could do something like this:

```
$rules = ValidationRule::whereIn('field_name', array_keys($request->all()))
                       ->pluck('field_rules', 'field_name');

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build a function in PHP that validates length depending on what you've put in DB you can validate the length with the insert.

```
INSERT
INTO
    users(username)(
        SELECT
            '".$_POST[' username']."'
        FROM
            settings
        WHERE
            settings.field = 'max_username'
            AND LENGTH('".$_POST[' username']."')<= settings.data
    )
```

Ofc you are not gonna use $_POST...